# Where do I find a producer/provider/processor implementation for XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation?

Tags: java, xml, annotations, xmladapter

Where do I find a producer/provider/processor implementation for XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation?

There must be some kind of implemetation for this.

That transforms a String to a class

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyIntegerAdapter.class)
private Integer myValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just google it ;) or use/view/decompile this class:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html